# Как вывести дерево категорий?

Tags: php, json

Дан массив:

```
$shop_categories = [
[
    'title' => 'Компьютеры',
    'children' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Ноутбуки',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Моноблоки',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Системные блоки',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Tower',
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'Mini Tower',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
[
    'title' => 'Бытовая техника',
    'children' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Пылесосы',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Холодильники',
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

Вывести дерево категорий в виде:

Компьютеры:

- Ноутбуки
- Моноблоки
- Системные блоки
- Tower
- Mini Tower

Бытовая техника:

- Пылесосы
- Холодильники

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
$shop_categories = [
    [ 'title' => 'Компьютеры',
        'children' => [
            [ 'title' => 'Ноутбуки', ],
            [ 'title' => 'Моноблоки', ],
            [ 'title' => 'Системные блоки',
                'children' => [
                    [ 'title' => 'Tower', ],
                    [ 'title' => 'Mini Tower', ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [ 'title' => 'Бытовая техника',
        'children' => [
            [ 'title' => 'Пылесосы', ],
            [ 'title' => 'Холодильники', ]
        ]
    ]
];
function write_title($title, $level) {
    for($i = 0; $i< $level; ++$i) {
        echo '--';
    }
    echo $title.PHP_EOL;
}
function print_tree(array $data, $level = 0) {
    foreach($data as $node) {
        write_title($node['title'], $level);
        if(array_key_exists('children', $node)) {
            print_tree($node['children'], $level + 1);
        }
    }
}

print_tree($shop_categories, 0);
```

[результат](http://ideone.com/2T9nQM)

Comment: Спасибо огромное Работает так как надо!